# Wavein_DataAvailable gives twice as much data as expected

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm reading data from the microphone using Naudio, but getting twice as much data as I expected considering the waveform I'm using.

```
... bunch of constructor code ....

    waveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 8, 1);

    bwp_MicToModem = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat);
    bwp_MicToModem.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
    bwp_MicToModem.BufferLength = 1000;
    bwp_MicToModem.ReadFully = false;

    wavein = new WaveIn();
    wavein.DeviceNumber = 0;
    wavein.BufferMilliseconds = 50;
    wavein.DataAvailable += Wavein_DataAvailable;
 }

private void Wavein_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    bwp_MicToModem.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    threadSafeAppendText("data event, bytes " + e.BytesRecorded, true);
}
```

This kinda works, but produces 800 bytes of data every 50 ms.

From my log file:

```
2019-03-27 14:41:26.765 : data event, bytes 800
2019-03-27 14:41:26.775 : readRate (ms) 0 numBytes 63
2019-03-27 14:41:26.775 : writeRate, modem.write (ms) 47 bytesFrMic 400
2019-03-27 14:41:26.785 : readRate (ms) 0 numBytes 96
2019-03-27 14:41:26.795 : readRate (ms) 3 numBytes 1
2019-03-27 14:41:26.805 : readRate (ms) 0 numBytes 63
2019-03-27 14:41:26.815 : readRate (ms) 0 numBytes 64
2019-03-27 14:41:26.815 : data event, bytes 800
```

If my maths isn't quite off, 8000 Hz of 1 byte (8 bits) (i.e = 8000 bytes/s of data) should equal 400 bytes/50 ms?

Had a look at the 800 bytes I got, and it all looks legit, as in not filled up with zeroes or something like that.

Anyone with an idea where I might go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually capturing at 8 bit because you never set `WaveIn.WaveFormat`. The `WaveIn` object will be able to tell you what `WaveFormat` it is capturing audio at, which will be 16 bit by default.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it :)